# "I made it to the finals" in a formal way?

Tags: formality

Is it okay to say that my team "made it" to the finals in a formal letter?
If not what else can I say?

Comment: That's pretty standard language so I would think it would be OK. How formal is the letter?

Comment: I'm listing my achievements to a university I'm applying to.

Comment: 'enter final' sounds more formal to me, and is [more widely used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enter+final%2Center+the+finals%2Cmake+it+to+the+finals&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Center%20final%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Center%20the%20finals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20it%20to%20the%20finals%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: How about "reached" instead of "made it to"?

Comment: @AndySchweig I think that was what I was looking for, could you write an answer.

Comment: @AndySchweig yeah, [reach final is even better](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enter+final%2Center+the+finals%2Cmake+it+to+the+finals%2Creach+final%2Creach+the+finals&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Center%20final%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Center%20the%20finals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20it%20to%20the%20finals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creach%20final%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creach%20the%20finals%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: We were **finalists**.  All of these expressions imply that your team did not win, since otherwise you would have stated "We won the... competition." "We were winners of..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My team reached the finals" is probably a little more formal than "My team made it to the finals."